# COLMAP fails to get SfM from some images

Tags: colmap

I am trying to obtain SfM (Structure from Motion) using COLMAP, but it seems like COLMAP fails to obtain SfM for a few images. For example, when I input 200 images into COLMAP, it only works for 190 images, and the SfM does not seem to come out properly for the remaining images.

It might be that the features of the images are not being extracted properly, or the features are too poor for matching to work correctly.

However, I want to extract SfM for all images, even if it may be inaccurate.

I am not using the GUI but running COLMAP through bash commands. Could there be a way to solve this issue by adjusting the parameters in the feature extraction or matching parts?

Error code like below.

```
==============================================================================
Global bundle adjustment
==============================================================================

iter      cost      cost_change  |gradient|   |step|    tr_ratio  tr_radius  ls_iter  iter_time  total_time
   0  2.425767e+04    0.00e+00    4.75e+03   0.00e+00   0.00e+00  1.00e+04        0    2.13e-02    7.73e-02

CHOLMOD version 3.0.14, Oct 22, 2019: Symbolic Analysis: status: OK
  Architecture: Linux
    sizeof(int):      4
    sizeof(SuiteSparse_long):  8
    sizeof(void *):   8
    sizeof(double):   8
    sizeof(Int):      4 (CHOLMOD's basic integer)
    sizeof(BLAS_INT): 4 (integer used in the BLAS)
  Results from most recent analysis:
    Cholesky flop count: 6.0089e+07
    Nonzeros in L:       2.3079e+05
  memory blocks in use:          11
  memory in use (MB):           0.1
  peak memory usage (MB):       0.6
  maxrank:    update/downdate rank:   8
  supernodal control: 1 40 (supernodal if flops/lnz >= 40)
  nmethods:   number of ordering methods to try: 1
    method 0: natural
        flop count: 6.0089e+07
        nnz(L):     2.3079e+05
  OK
   1  2.422195e+04    3.57e+01    1.82e+01   3.64e-01   1.00e+00  3.00e+04        1    1.49e-01    2.27e-01
   2  2.422186e+04    9.11e-02    5.54e+00   2.63e-01   1.00e+00  9.00e+04        1    1.03e-01    3.29e-01
   3  2.422185e+04    1.25e-02    1.92e+00   3.27e-01   1.00e+00  2.70e+05        1    1.22e-01    4.52e-01
   4  2.422184e+04    2.20e-03    1.98e+00   2.26e-01   9.99e-01  8.10e+05        1    9.35e-02    5.45e-01
   5  2.422184e+04    4.38e-04    8.43e-01   1.20e-01   1.00e+00  2.43e+06        1    1.00e-01    6.46e-01


Bundle adjustment report
------------------------
    Residuals : 95226
   Parameters : 36124
   Iterations : 6
         Time : 0.647089 [s]
 Initial cost : 0.504716 [px]
   Final cost : 0.504343 [px]
  Termination : Convergence

  => Merged observations: 1
  => Completed observations: 0
  => Filtered observations: 1
  => Changed observations: 0.000042
  => Filtered images: 0
  => No good initial image pair found.
```